# Simple NAS setup for Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, networking, nfs, ldap, nas

So, I want to connect my shiny new NAS (QNAP TS-210p II) to my Ubuntu 11.10 box. I have a 2nd Ubuntu machine, but I don't use that enough to be too worried about it. Use is ideally to offload all storage except for system (which can then run off a 30GB flash drive). The main machine also runs Myth front/backends. Both are on a wired network currently.

I have got a basic setup working, mounted over NFS, but have some issues, and whenever I look for answers, I seem to get unto the UbuntuServer domain, with what seems like more detail than I want in an answer.

Questions I have identified so far:

1) Sharing UIDs to get file permissions correct. LDAP or something else? What is necessary to make this work?

2) Mounting an NFS device reliably. Do I just add it in `fstab` or is some sort of auto-mount advisable? Its a wired network, but I shouldn't need to worry about reboot after power-outages and sequencing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sharing UIDs**

Assuming that the NAS is running a variant of Linux, and you have root access (if not I guess you need to ask QNAP), you have three options:

- Manually sync `/etc/passwd` between the two boxes (`passwd` is the file that contains the username/userid mapping).
- LDAP
- NIS

If there are just a few users that don't change very often, the manual sync is probably the simplest. You need to keep the NAS system users the same, just add the relevant client users. Make a copy of the passwd file before changing it, so you can revert if necessary.

See the [Ubuntu NFS HowTo, User Permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo#User_Permissions).

**Mounting**

Mounting in `fstab` is probably the simplest.

Something like

```
//my-nas/share   /mnt/nas    nfs   rw,hard,intr    0  0
```

should do the trick.

The `hard` and `intr` mount options are recommended by the [Linux NFS HowTo](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s04.html). They will cause client programs to hang if the NAS is down (`hard`), but will let you kill them (`intr`). *(The alternative is that file access returns an error, which according to the Linux NFS HowTo most programs cannot handle gracefully, and is "a recipe for corrupted files and lost data".)*

Comment: Manually syncing `passwd` is an idea that I'd not even considered. It should be easy because of course I only have a couple of UIDs to worry about.